# Handling array inside of array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
    Bid : { id : 20,
              rows: [ 
             {rowid : 1, name : "RowOne", 
              supp :[
                    {suppId : 1, name : "SuppOne"},
                    {suppId : 2, name : "SuppTwo"}]
             },
             {rowid : 1, name : "RowOne", 
             supp :[
                    {suppId : 1, name : "SuppOne"},
                    {suppId : 2, name : "SuppTwo"}]
             }
      ]}
```

What would the best way to manage such data in MongoDb? 
Keeping such a structure would make it really difficult to update or remove any element from supp array

I found two solutions for this

1. Keeping supp array into another collection keeping supp object
2. Making dynamic schema. Rather than making row into an array, I would keep it as a object. For example, row1 or row2 would key for object. Hence, row1 object will have an array of supp.

Are these the only solution? Which might be the best?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you store nested data then certainly it is going to create problem in updating and searching element. For example if you want to search a particular element of array then it would be very difficult to do that. You can not just perform search query easily. Although its not impossible but its not recommended.

Now unitl and unless you see some redundancy in saving data you should not store them in a single object.

I have faced same kind of problem by storing nested array objects